# Error with pip install

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the module [aplpy](http://aplpy.github.io/install.html) via `pip install aplpy`, but I keep getting an error message (see [here](http://txt.do/1y6n)). It looks like there is some kind of conflict with Anaconda; do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the locale of your terminal

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this every time I open a new terminal?

Comment: Yes, of course. Add these lines to your ~/.bash_profile if you are using mac or ~/.bashrc on linux.

Comment: @IritMalka Which of those to use is a bit more complex than Mac vs Linux. If you might not always use Bash, `$HOME/.profile` is better, but it requires slightly different syntax.